# Compiler does not error out when a COM property is incorrect / missing?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, vb6, com-interop

I have a VB6 project that currently Compiles even though I am accessing a Property that does not exist.

The code looks a bit like this:

```
Public vizSvrEmp As VizualServer.Employees
Set vizSvrEmp = New VizualServer.Employees

Fn = FreeFile
Open vizInfo.Root & "FILE.DAT" For Random As #Fn Len = RecLen
Do While Not EOF(Fn)
    Get #Fn, , ClkRecord
    With vizSvrEmp
        Index = .Add(ClkRecord.No)
        .NotAvailable(Index) = ClkRecord.NotAvailable
        .Bananas(Index) = ClkRecord.Start
        'Plus lots more properties
    End With
Loop
```

The `Bananas` property does not exist in the object yet it still compiles.
My `vizSvrEmp` Object is a .NET COM Interop DLL and is early bound and if I type the dot in I get the Intellisense correctly (which does *not* show Bananas)

I tried removing the `With` but that behaves the same

How can I make sure these errors are picked up by the compiler?

Comment: Use Option Strict On at the top of the source code file.

Comment: @HansPassant - this is VB6 so no Option Strict Available :-)

Comment: Oh, what the heck was it?  Option Explicit is next.  Update your question and show the declaration for vizSvrEmp.  If it is not declared with the `As` keyword then no Option will help you.

Comment: @HansPassant - Option Explicit is already in every code module. I have updated the question as requested

Comment: Next you need to document what [InterfaceType] and/or [ClassInterface] attributes you used in the .NET code.  If you didn't specify AutoDual then it is still late-bound.

Comment: @HansPassant - I was using the standard ComClass template: `<ComClass(General.ClassId, General.InterfaceId, General.EventsId)> _` I changed this to `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> _` and it now fails to compile. Can you make your last comment an answer and explain *why* it is still late bound with the first option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've got this sorted out with the help of Hans but just for completeness, the alternative to using `ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)` is to use `ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)` and then Implement an explicit interface that is decorated with `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>`.

It is more work, but gives you complete control over the interface GUIDs.  The AutoDual will auto generate unique GUIDs for the interfaces when you compile, which is time saving but you don't have control over them.

In use, this would look something like this:

```
<ComVisible(True), _
Guid(Guids.IEmployeeGuid), _
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface IEmployee 

   <DispIdAttribute(1)> _
   ReadOnly Property FirstName() As String

   <DispIdAttribute(2)> _
   ReadOnly Property LastName() As String

   <DispIdAttribute(3)> _
   Function EtcEtc(ByVal arg As String) As Boolean

End Interface


<ComVisible(True), _
Guid(Guids.EmployeeGuid), _
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public NotInheritable Class Employee
   Implements IEmployee 

   Public ReadOnly Property FirstName() As String Implements IEmployee.FirstName
      Get
         Return "Santa"
      End Get
   End Function

   'etc, etc

End Class
```

Note how the GUIDs are declared.  I find creating a helper class to consolidate the GUIDs and provide Intellisense works out well:

```
Friend Class Guids
   Public Const AssemblyGuid As String = "BEFFC920-75D2-4e59-BE49-531EEAE35534"   
   Public Const IEmployeeGuid As String = "EF0FF26B-29EB-4d0a-A7E1-687370C58F3C"
   Public Const EmployeeGuid As String = "DE01FFF0-F9CB-42a9-8EC3-4967B451DE40"
End Class
```

Finally, I use these at the assembly level:

```
'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid(Guids.AssemblyGuid)> 

'NOTE:  The following attribute explicitly hides the classes, methods, etc in 
'        this assembly from being exported to a TypeLib.  We can then explicitly 
'        expose just the ones we need to on a case-by-case basis.
<Assembly: ComVisible(False)> 
<Assembly: ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
```